# Dissolving polygons based on spectral differences from QGIS?

Tags: qgis, dissolve

I'm looking for a package or algorithm that allows to dissolve polygons based on their spectral characteristics and a threshold defined by the user in QGIS. Equivalent to what the "Spectral Differences" algorithm does in eCognition.

I did a segmentation using the Meanshift algorithm of the OTB in QGIS, based on a three band image of Sentinel 2 satellite. I want to analyze some oversegmented polygons, and dissolve them with their neighbours if their spectral differences are less than a certain threshold.

Does anyone knows of a tool that does this kind of work? or something similar at least? I haven't found anything in the web, but I suppose there might be someone who has already done it.